# Magento Copy To New Server - No Errors Logged, displays white page

Tags: php, apache, magento

I am trying to move a magento installation (v1.5.0.1) to a new server and new url.  I have followed the instructions here (with the exception that I want to keep my current version of magento and extensions)-

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server

The admin login works, but nothing is displayed below the header after I login.  The ajax search box on admin shows my products when I start typing, but the product page is never displayed.

The store home page shows a blank page.

I have checked both apache and magento logs and neither shows any exceptions.

I have tried to copy this to my dev Windows machine and another linux server.  Both have the same result.  The database seems to be working fine, but something in the rendering of the page is breaking and getting eaten up by Magento.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, im having exactly the same issue.. Did you ever solve it? I have tried disabling magento compiler but nothing, deleted var folder.. This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the php error logs?  Did you try turning on display_errors in your php.ini file?

Comment: yep- php errors are enabled and nothing is showing in the apache / php logs.

Answer (score 0):

The following files and folders need their permissions set to the number 777 or 750

/var/.htaccess

/app/etc

/var

Comment: It would be worth explaining *why* this would help to make your answer more useful.